# how use xargs with grep and head for get first ocurrence of each website?

Tags: html, grep, head

in each page i have multiple links of png  I need obtain the second png link of each page but this command only get the second link of first page

how i could solve

```
echo "linkh\nlfinkh\nlinekh\nli3nkh\n"|xargs  -d '\n' -n1 -I  % curl  -s -N 'https://www.myweb.org/images?q=%'  |  grep -shoP "(http).*?(png|jpg|jpeg)" |sed -n 2p
```

this command only output one link

I need to output four link (the second link of each page)

please help me

https://www.myweb.org/images?q=linkh
the first page have a http:ffeefe.png

https://www.myweb.org/images?q=lfinkh
the second  page have a http:f43feefe.png

https://www.myweb.org/images?q=linekh
the third   page have a http:f433feefe.png

https://www.myweb.org/images?q=li3nkh
the fourth    page have a http:f435feefe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code finds only the first result because you pipe the html of all four pages combined into one instance of `grep`, which then finds the first match. Instead, you want to run `grep` four times, once for each page. One straightforward way to solve this problem is to use a loop instead of `xargs`:

```
echo -e "linkh\nlfinkh\nlinekh\nli3nkh"|
  while read x; do
    curl  -s -N 'https://www.myweb.org/images?q=$x' |
    grep -shoP "(http).*?(png|jpg|jpeg)" |
    sed -n 2p
  done
```